# creating a new canvas VS clearRect

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a text caching system for html5 canvas. I need to know which one gives better performance. Clearing the existing canvas using clearRect or creating the canvas once again?

Edit: Added some codes.

```
function textBuffer(text, font, fill="white", stroke=false, lw=0) {
    let buffer = document.createElement("canvas");
    let bCtx = buffer.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = font;
    let d = ctx.measureText(text);
    buffer.width = d.width + lw * 2;
    buffer.height = parseInt(font.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")) + lw;
    bCtx.font = font;
    bCtx.textBaseline = "top"
    if(stroke) {
        bCtx.lineWidth = lw;
        bCtx.strokeStyle = stroke;
        bCtx.strokeText(text, lw / 2, lw / 2);
    }
    bCtx.fillStyle = fill;
    bCtx.fillText(text, lw / 2, lw / 2);
    return buffer;
}
```

Here's the other code which uses clearRect instead of creating the canvas once again.

```
class Text {
    ...
    render() {
        ctx.font = this.font;
        this.canvas.width = ctx.measureText(this.text).width;
        this.canvas.height = this.fontSize;
        this.ctx.clearRect(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

        this.ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        this.ctx.textAlign = "center";
        this.ctx.font = this.font;
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeColor;
        this.ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        if(this.strokeColor) {
            this.ctx.strokeText(this.text, 0, 0);
        }
        this.ctx.fillText(this.text, 0, 0);

        return this.canvas;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code so we are all in the same page?

Comment: i added my codes. @JoseA.Ayllón

Comment: What browsers are you supporting? What screen resolutions? Are mobile devices supported?  ____ ____ __ I would imagine that deleting the canvas and creating the canvas once again, will add some flickering to the application, but cases like this you have to test, test, and test some more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this method several times, then use the second version, definitely.

Generating a new canvas element and its context will waste memory, and thus will force the Garbage Collector to kick in more often, which may cause your whole app to slow down.

However, since you do resize your canvas, note that you don't need the `clearRect` call, its already clear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. didn't know about that.